# Partitioning not working need primary key?

Tags: mysql, partitioning

We are trying some partitioning as below.

```
ALTER TABLE tblreceipt PARTITION BY RANGE (MONTH(receiptDate)) 
( 
PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2012-10-20')), 
PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2012-10-21')), 
PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2012-10-22')) 
);
```

but end up with this Error Code: 1503 
A PRIMARY KEY must include all columns in the table's partitioning function

I have done the changes now.

```
ALTER TABLE tblreceipt PARTITION BY RANGE (receiptDate) 
( 
PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN '2012-10-20', 
PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN '2012-10-21', 
PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN '2012-10-22' 
);

Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''2012-10-20', 
PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN '2012-10-21', 
PARTITION p3 VALUES ' at line 3
```

Comment: The problem is that the function (`MONTH()`) and the `LESS THAN` values are incompatible.  Apart from the fact that I don't see the value of using `TO_DAYS()` (what is the advantage there compared to a simple date?), you should use `TO_DAYS(receiptDate)`.  Or, more simply (if you want a day-by-day partitioning), just `RANGE (receiptDate) ... LESS THAN '2012-10-20'`.

Comment: @dezso I have done the changes accordingly but I get a syntax error now?

Comment: Then let's look at the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-range.html), as the error message advises.  Then it becomes clear that I missed the parentheses...  I'll compile an answer now.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the function (`MONTH()`) and the `LESS THAN` values are incompatible.

Apart from the fact that I don't see the value of using `TO_DAYS()` (what is the advantage there compared to a simple date?), you should use `(TO_DAYS(receiptDate))` instead of `(MONTH(receiptDate))`.

Or, more simply (if you want a day-by-day partitioning), I'd write just

```
RANGE COLUMNS (receiptDate) 
... 
LESS THAN ('2012-10-20')
```

See a very simple working example at [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/66c5e).

Comment: @dezo I tried RANGE (receiptDate) ..... LESS THAN ('2012-10-20') it gives me this error Error Code: 1064
VALUES value must be of same type as partition function near '), 
PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN ('2012-10-21'), 
PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN' at line 3

Comment: What type receipDate is?  The code chunk I included works for date type.

Comment: The receiptDate is of date type only not datetime.

Comment: Well, I confused things once again.  Edited my answer, look at the `COLUMNS` keyword.

Comment: Unfortunately is still the same error Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'COLUMNS (receiptDate) 
( 
PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN ('2012-10-20'), 
PARTITI' at line 1

Comment: @newbie14 What's your MySQL version?  Have you checked the SQLFiddle?

Comment: I checked it is 5.1 which I guess is too old right I will upgrade it soon and get back to you on that. Thank you.